# Accept array row values based on priority to form comma separated string

Tags: c#, .net

I have a jagged array

```
string[][] toMerge;

toMerge[0] = {"School", "Train", "Bag", "Choclate", " ", " "}; 
toMerge[1] = {"College", " ", " " , "chicken", " ", " "}; 
toMerge[2] = {"work", "car", " ", "Burger", " ", " "};
```

have another single dimensional array

```
string[] order = {"College", "Work", "School"};
```

I need to order the jagged array by checking the first column of the jagged array with order array and based on the order I need to select the column values and generate a comma separated string.

In above case output should be

```
String output = "College, Car, Bag, Chicken, , ";
```

Could someone help me with the shortest code I can write for this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not a code writing service. **Could someone help me with the shortest code I can write for this.**

Comment: It is very hard to judge your ability to write code and hence finding "the shortest code *I can write* for this" is not answerable in verifiable way. I think this question is not only too broad but also opinion based as correct judgement of your ability to write code is clearly an opinion. (Showing what you've tried would help for SO question, clarifying rules of the puzzle could make it ok on [codegolf.se])

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            string[][] toMerge = {
                new string[] {"School", "Train", "Bag", "Choclate", " ", " "}, 
                new string[] {"College", " ", " " , "chicken", " ", " "},
                new string[] {"work", "car", " ", "Burger", " ", " "}
                                  };

            List<string> results = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < toMerge.First().Count(); i++)
            {
                string min = toMerge.Where(x => x[i].Trim().Length > 0).Select(x => x[i]).Min();
                results.Add(min == null ? " " : min);

            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",results));
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank You very much JdWeng. But here the one dimensional array prescribes the order is not referenced right. In my question order[]. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: If you want a one dimensional array then use SelectMany to reduce the two dimensions to one dimension.

Comment: I need to
- Order the multidimensional array based on its first column.
- Another single dimensional array is referenced to find the order by checking the first column of multidimensional array.

- Once ordered, I need to take only the values from first row of the ordered multidimensional array.
- If any value is empty in first row, take that from second row.
- Keep empty

Comment: In that way we can control the order by changing the entries in order array

Comment: Thank you very much, but now also you haven't referenced order array for finding the order I think. Thid is where I was really struggling. Thanks very much for your kind help.
string[] order = {"College", "Work", "School"};

When ordering the multidimensional array, we need to reference above single dimensional array.

Comment: I have found a way to reference the order array.
 String[] outputStr = sortedTempArray.Cast<string[]>().GroupBy(x => x.First()).Select(x => string.Join(",", x.SelectMany(y => y).Where(y => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(y)).Distinct())).ToArray();

But now I am struggling to get LINQ select to select only one entry per column, that means currently I am getting as below.

"Work,Car, ,Burger, , ,School,Train,Bag,Choclate, , , College, , , Chicken, , "

but I want only "WORK,Car,Bag,Burger, , " 
That means I will check te priority row first if te value exists, I'll take that. else second row value

Comment: MIN get the order.